# Error 413: Request entity is too large, nginx

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx version 1.10.3, it returns error 413 request entity is too large, when uploading file of larger than 5 MB, however in nginx.conf I have already configured client_max_body_size is 20M.

```
server {
  client_max_body_size 20M;
  listen 80;
  ---
  ---
}
}
```

Comment: First off, have you reloaded Nginx since saving the new configuration, and second, is your server configured to handle that size? You haven't mentioned anything about the backend code, but for example, I do know that PHP has limits on request entity sizes that you would need to increase too

Comment: If your backend is PHP-based app, you may also need to change the [`post_max_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) setting value in your PHP-FPM pool configuration file (usually `/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf`).